# Split floating point number into fractional and integral parts

Tags: c++

I'm writing a template class designed to work with any floating point type. For some of the methods I need to split a number into its integral and fractional parts. With primitive floating point types I can just cast to an integer to truncate the fractional part, but this wouldn't work with a big number class. Ideally my class would only use the four basic arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) in its calculations.

The method below is the solution I came up with. All it does is subtract powers of ten until the original number is less than 1. It works well, but seems like a brute-force approach. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
template< typename T >
class Math
{
    public:

    static T modf( T const & x, T & intpart )
    {
        T sub = 1;
        T ret = x;

        while( x >= sub )
        {
            sub *= 10;
        }

        sub /= 10;

        while( sub >= 1 )
        {
            while( ret >= sub )
            {
                ret -= sub;
            }

            sub /= 10;

        }//while [sub] > 0

        intpart = x - ret;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note that I've removed the sign management code for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps replace the subtraction loop with a binary search, although that's not an improvement in complexity class.

What you have requires a number of subtractions approximately equal to the sum of the decimal digits of `x`, whereas a binary search requires a number of addition-and-divide-by-two operations approximately equal to 3-and-a-bit times the number of decimal digits of `x`.

With what you're doing and with the binary search, there's no particular reason to use powers of 10 when looking for the upper bound, you could use any number. Some other number might be a bit quicker on average, although it probably depends on the type `T`.

Btw, I would also be tempted to make `modf` a function template within `Math` (or a free template function in a namespace), rather than `Math` a class template. That way you can specialize or overload one function at a time for particular types (especially the built-in types) without having to specialize the whole of `Math`.

Example:

```
namespace Math
{
    template <typename T>
    T modf( T const & x, T & intpart )
    { ... }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
float f = 1.5, fint;
std::cout << Math::modf(f, fint) << '\n';

double d = 2.5, dint;
std::cout << Math::modf(d, dint) << '\n';

mpf_class ff(3.5), ffint(0);  // GNU multi-precision
std::cout << Math::modf(ff, ffint) << '\n';
```

Overload it like this:

```
namespace Math {
    double modf(double x, double &intpart) {
        return std::modf(x, &intpart);
    }

    mpf_class modf(const mpf_class &x, mpf_class &intpart) {
        intpart = floor(x);
        return x - intpart;
    }
}
```

Comment: this sounds like a good idea, can you give an example? I had considered making the methods themselves templates but wanted to keep the interface as caller-friendly as possible. Template syntax can be a nightmare sometimes :P

Comment: @PeddleSpam: the interface with a function template ought to end up more caller-friendly than what you have, because function templates can deduce their template arguments from the arguments provided to the call, whereas class templates have no such facility. Examples added.

Comment: I like the interface better, but for a type that didn't already have an overload the user would still have to call `Math::modf< mpf_class >( ff, ffint )`.

Comment: @PeddleSpam: that's not true. If there is no overload for type `T`, then `T t1, t2; Math::modf(t1, t2);` will automatically call `Math::modf<T>`. Try it.

Comment: It's how standard functions like `make_pair` work, or `back_inserter`. You can write `make_pair(1,2)` instead of having to write out something horribly verbose like `pair<int,int>(1,2)`. Which admittedly isn't verbose in the case of two ints, but would be for a pair consisting of two iterators, for example `pair<deque<unsigned long>::iterator, deque<unsigned long>::iterator>(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.end())` -> `make_pair(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.end())`

Comment: just out of curiosity I made a new function called `cmodf` that extracts the integer component of `x` by performing a cast `intpart = unsigned( abs( x ) )`. I then did a timed run of both functions using the same input data and the timings are almost identical, some 0.25% average difference. Is a cast really so inefficient?

Comment: What are you comparing the cast against?

Comment: the `cmodf` function is compared against the `modf` function given in my question.

Comment: @PeddleSpam: I would not expect the cast to be that slow, so if I got that result then I would closely examine the output of the compiler, to make sure it didn't optimize the benchmark away.

Comment: you're right it seemed to be removing the calls to both methods and only performing console output, probably because the variables storing the return values weren't used outside the loops. Now the timings show the `modf` method is around 10 times slower than `cmodf`, makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

mb use std::modf is better?
for custom type you can release Math class specialization.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Math
{
public:
    static T modf(const T& x, T& integral_part)
    {
        return std::modf(x, &integral_part);
    }
};

int main()
{
    double d_part = 0.;
    double res = Math<double>::modf(5.2123, d_part);
    std::cout << d_part << " " << res << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: std::modf is only overloaded for the primitive floating point types (float, double, long double)

Comment: Yes. Try this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/rounding/modf.html

Comment: The boost stuff only works if the type `T` has a conversion to an integral type, or if you write some specializations or overloads to "configure" your type for boost.math. In practice, configuring your type is probably the right thing to do, but it seems outside the scope of this question. "Ideally my class would only use the four basic arithmetic operations" -- what the questioner seems to want is a fall-back that works without needing separate work for each type.

Comment: that's pretty much what I wanted. Having the user configure their type to work with my class seems awkward. Would it be better to specify an interface the class requires and specialise for primitive types?

Comment: @PeddleSpam: it's awkward for whoever configures the type, but it's probably going to result in much more efficient operations. Most user-defined classes for handling numbers can return their own integer and fraction parts quickly, because they'll "know" where the decimal point is in their internal representation of the value. The best way is an interface of free functions that someone other than the class author can define. Then if person A wants to use your math templates with a type B whose author has never heard of your interface, A can do the config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how strict your "ideally use only mathematical operations" restraint is, but nonetheless for the fractional part, could you extract it to a string and convert back to a float?

Comment: converting the numbers to strings was one of my first ideas, but it would probably be even less efficient than what I have now.

Comment: I don't know the answer to how efficient it would be to use strings, but would this approach solve the typing issues you're currently having, making for a simpler and more generic template?